# Jenkins DSL job failing

Tags: jenkins, sbt

I'm using jenkins-dsl plugin.
After my seed job has finished successfully, my dsl config has created a new job as expected (Let's call the new created job "JobA").
JobA should run a sbt build step.
When running JobA for the first time it fail immediately with the following error:

```
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.SbtPluginBuilder.buildCmdLine(SbtPluginBuilder.java:159)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.SbtPluginBuilder.perform(SbtPluginBuilder.java:111)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:537)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:408)
```

However if I than go in jenkins ui into JobA config tab, I DO NOTHING, an, save the job, and than run the job again, it works!
DSL attached below.

Any suggestions?

```
job('JobA') {
scm {
    git {
        remote {
            github('XXXXXXX')
            credentials('XXXXXXXX')
        }
        createTag(false)
        branch('*/master')
    }
}

triggers {
    githubPush()
}

//sbt
steps {
    sbt('sbt',
            'clean compile test publish',
            '-Dsbt.log.noformat=true',
            '-Xmx2G -Xms512M')
}
}
```

Comment: Everything looks fine to me, and I can run a job generated with that DSL with no problems. Though I note that the same Java error is mentioned in https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22718 (though you perhaps have an older version of the plugin?) — but that doesn't readily explain why it works after saving the job again. As suggested below, doing a diff of the job's `config.xml` before and after saving would be interesting.

Answer (score 2):

try comparing JobA's xml config before and after saving the job (or better take snapshot for entire jobs) directory. You may find something.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've got the right number of parameters in the sbt call? [The API for sbt](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.step.StepContext.sbt) suggests there can/should be five. (I don't know which ones might be optional.)

Or maybe it has something to do with the `job` keyword? In the [migration notes](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Migration), section 1.30, it says that it has been deprecated in favour of other, more precise keywords. However, it is still often used in the following documentation.

If you call your DSL from a script, you should definitely adapt to, e.g., freeStyleJob.

Comment: The documentation says that only the first parameter to `sbt` is required; the other four default to `null`.